# Am i able to install Win 10 on a Macbook Pro '15 running Catalina (model no. 12,5) with/without bootcamp properly?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition, catalina

I'm running Catalina 10.15 on this 5 year old Macbook Pro, and i was wondering if it could install the free version of Win 10 (possibly upgrading to full Windows 10 Home after) with the installer or media creation tool, preferably. I've researched other people change to Windows only using third-party tools not Bootcamp only (creating a partition for the OS, have a USB stick, then deleting macos and finally adding the drivers and programs needed).

Bootcamp would be my other choice of course if it isn't possible with either the model i have or macOS version. Hoping to have just Windows 10 on it because i am fed up with macOS and its limitations (don't know why i bought it back then, lol). Heard bootcamp does have a few kinks like boot time and other software stuff on Mac so thats why i'm not planning to do it like that.

So if anyone that knows all this well could get me through this, it'd be cool! Am decent with computers and all but not too savvy on Macs/macOS. Thanks.

Comment: This is my 1st time with this though, just to clarify.

Comment: Seems i got it to work! Boot time and software experience is quick and just as i thought it should!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a USB Windows 10 installer, the process if fairly simple.

1. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Windows Support Software (the drivers).
2. Download the Windows 10 ISO from [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
3. Erase a 16 GB or larger flash drive. Use the Master Boot Record scheme and ExFAT format.
4. Copy the files from the Windows Support Software download and Windows 10 ISO to the flash drive.

If you do not wish to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10 to the internal drive, then apply the following steps.

1. If you are going to keep some existing partitions, then create free space or contiguous partitions which can be deleted during the Windows installation.
2. Restart the Mac and hold down the option key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear.
3. Select the `EFI Boot` under the external drive icon.
4. When asked for a Product Key, you can select to skip this step. If you skip, then at some point (30 days?) you will need to enter a product key.
5. During the installation, either erase the entire internal drive or install to available free space. This may require first deleting any unneeded partitions.

Comment: Idk if its the Windows 10 ISO or my MacBook/bootcamp not providing the correct driver to install. Most videos about the setup screen goes to product key, then choosing where to install. Maybe its cause of 1909/2004 installation and i need an older one..

Comment: Nvm i got it setup

Answer (score 0):

### In a word, yes.

It seems to be a 2015 15-inch MacBook Pro with a core i7 Processor. That is plenty of horsepower to install Windows, assuming you have enough disk space to dedicate to Windows (I wouldn't go less than 20GB) it should work fine.

Not sure what you mean about the free version of Windows 10, though. While Microsoft did give free licenses to people upgrading from previous versions of Windows I am unsure if that is still in effect. And as you are not really upgrading a version of Windows, you don't qualify under those rules.

However, you are welcome to give it a try. Apple has some info on what to do and how to do it [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468). I would have a look at all of Apple's documentation on the subject so you are familiar with the process.

Once you have done so put an ISO of Windows 10 on your Mac (you can download a copy but without a license key, you won't get far) get out an 8GB USB key that has nothing on it that you can't afford to lose. and run the Boot Camp Assistant in your Applications folder. It's pretty good and will walk you through the steps required to install Windows 10 on your Mac, turning it into a Dual OS bootable Mac with Catalina and Windows 10 on it.

Plan on it taking a couple of hours for the whole process. As much because doing this takes some time and also requires you to *pay close attention* to the process so you don't screw it up.

Also note that since you are re-partitioning your internal hard drive (where macOS and all your Apps and files reside) it would be a **really good idea** to make a full backup of your Mac before proceeding.

I have done this a number of times and had no problems nor had any data loss but then I have been doing Mac support since... Well, let's just say the first Mac I have any experience with is a second generation 512K Macintosh (the so called "Fat Mac") So this stuff is second nature to me. And likely not to you, so pay attention and follow the directions carefully.

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant does not use a USB key to install Windows 10 on a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Comment: You do not need a license (Product Key) to install Windows 10 on a Mac. However, at some point after installing you will need a license to continue using Windows.

Comment: Curious, I have done it on a number of Macs, just not my own. Well that makes it easier as Boot Camp Assistant will use the Mac HD as a source and you don't need to create a bootable USB key.

Comment: The 1909 version of Windows 10 would accept the product key from older versions of Windows. I am not sure if this is true the the 2004 release.

Comment: Thanks for the help/answers! Yeah, also i don't know if i should do the latest 2004 Win 10 release, maybe it wont work?? Dk if a older 1909 version is out there. Technically there is no "free" Windows 10, u can use it after installation with limitations without a key.

Comment: Rule 1 of Windows: "never install major updates right away." (macOS too, for that matter) give it at least a couple of months, long enough for MS (and Apple) and all the other users to report on issues, release patches or warn you away.

Comment: Hey I cant get past the "select drivers"  screen on Windows Setup. I thought I'd get to the product screen after selecting my language during the 1st few steps. Its blank and you cant select any of the driver options in bootcamps Windows support software. Don't think I'm suppose to have that screen.